# 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode' in EmailMessage

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, attributeerror

I am trying to make an app in Django which accepts information from user and send a HTML template as pdf through an e-mail to the user. But I am getting this error
**'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'**

Here is my view for the email

```
def email(request, serial_no):
    user = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=serial_no)
    # roll_no = {'roll': str(user['roll_no'])}
    html = render_to_string('card.html',
                            {'user': user})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename={}'.format(user.roll_no + '.pdf')
    pdf = weasyprint.HTML(string=html, base_url='').write_pdf(
        stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(string='body { font-family: serif}')])
    to_emails = [str(user.roll_no) + '@gmail.com']
    subject = "Certificate from Nami Montana"
    email = EmailMessage(subject, body=pdf, from_email='SSC', to=to_emails)
    email.attach("{}".format(user.roll_no) + '.pdf', pdf, "application/pdf")
    email.content_subtype = "pdf"  # Main content is now text/html
    email.encoding = 'utf-8'
    email.send()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('id_card:submit'))
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Documents\GitHub\SSC-Website\id_card\views.py", line 49, in email
    email.send()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\console.py", line 34, in send_messages
    self.write_message(message)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\console.py", line 17, in write_message
    msg = message.message()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 246, in message
    msg = SafeMIMEText(self.body, self.content_subtype, encoding)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 159, in __init__
    MIMEText.__init__(self, _text, _subtype=_subtype, _charset=_charset)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\mime\text.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 167, in set_payload
    has_long_lines = any(
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 168, in <genexpr>
    len(line.encode()) > RFC5322_EMAIL_LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace

Comment: You encode `str` (Unicode strings).  You decode `bytes` (byte strings).  `line` is a byte string, so can't be encoded.  Can't tell most of the types in your code because it is incomplete.  Make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending a PDF file object as the message body:

```py
pdf = weasyprint.HTML(string=html, base_url='').write_pdf(
        stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(string='body { font-family: serif}')])
email = EmailMessage(subject, body=pdf, from_email='SSC', to=to_emails)
```

`EmailMessage` attempts to encode the `body` with the utf-8 codec, but the body is a PDF file object, which is `bytes`, and `bytes` doesn't provide an `encode` method only a `decode` method. The correct way to add a PDF to an email is to attach it as you've done later in your code. Now, if you want the email body to be the text of the PDF file, get the text in a `str` and pass it as the `body` kwarg.

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me with one more problem?  When I am trying to open the pdf with Adobe Reader, it says "There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document (135)".

Comment: @BibekPaul, there are probably some unsupported characters (by Adobe Reader) in the file. Try opening it with Chrome or https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/.

Comment: Would you be able to point out which characters are those if i show you the html code

Comment: @BibekPaul, no, I don't know all of the unsupported utf-8 characters, I just know that this has been an issue in the past. My best advice is to look at the PDF in a viewer which supports the characters and suspect the strange, rare ones.